# Fail to upload chart to chartmuseum

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

As https://github.com/kubernetes-helm/chartmuseum, I set up chartmuseum by running `helm install incubator/chartmuseum` in Kubernetes cluster.

When I want to upload chart by running

`curl --data-binary "@mychart-0.1.0.tgz" http://$URL:$PORT/api/charts`

it returns `404 page not found` even if i run it in the container which chartmuseum running on.

Comment: same problem...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By default helm chart `incubator/chartmuseum` installs with `DISABLE_API: true` parameter, so, that's why any request to `/api` don't work (returns 404).

You need to install helm chart `incubator/chartmuseum` with `DISABLE_API: false` parameter:

```
helm install incubator/chartmuseum --set env.open.DISABLE_API=false
```

**EDIT:**

Helm chart `incubator/chartmuseum` was [moved](https://github.com/helm/charts/pull/4601) to `stable/chartmuseum` on Apr 6, 2018.

Now you need to install helm chart `stable/chartmuseum` with `DISABLE_API: false` parameter:

```
helm install stable/chartmuseum --set env.open.DISABLE_API=false
```

After that you can perform any operations with its API, for example:

```
$ curl --data-binary "@mychart-0.1.0.tgz" http://localhost:8080/api/charts
{"saved":true}

$ curl http://localhost:8080/api/charts
{"mychart":[{"name":"mychart","version":"0.1.0","description":"A Helm chart for Kubernetes","apiVersion":"v1","urls":["charts/mychart-0.1.0.tgz"],"created":"2018-02-11T12:51:15.763951001Z","digest":"ae8d7138002d432014dc8638ec37202823e9207445caf08a660d154b26e936ea"}]}
```

Comment: thanks! it works as expected. I even read through the code and thought it set to false as default.

Comment: `chartmuseum` is moved to stable repository, so now the command should be `helm stable/chartmuseum --set env.open.DISABLE_API=false`

Comment: Thank you @MajusMisiak. Added this information to the answer.

Comment: When I execute 
curl http://localhost:9999/api/charts
{"error":"unauthorized"}. What the default credentials?

Comment: I enabled AUTH_ANONYMOUS_GET then I lost the unauthorized error. But now when I am trying to get the charts, I am getting this
``` [root@centos7 harbor]# curl http://localhost:9999/api/charts
{"error":"not found"}``` But DISABLE_API is false. What could be the issue?